# Populating docker-machine with docker-compose

Tags: docker

**Edit**
How can I start containers on a docker-machine with docker compose?

I have provisioned 3 docker machines and joined two as workers to one master machine. However, none of my code or services seem to be present in the machine.  How can I run a docker-compose file on a docker machine?

Normally in development I run `docker-compose up`.  However, docker-compose is unavailable on the box. I'm not sure at what point the machine starts running the docker containers or how that can be done.  I passed the `docker-compose.prod.yml` as part of the creating the stack. `echo docker stack deploy -c docker-compoe.prod.yml app`.

Very new to all of this coming from Heroku.  Just wondering if the only way to do this is to ssh into every box and manually copy files over.

I would expect to be able to `docker-machine ssh host`.  And then inside of that shell be able to `docker-compose up`.

If it's true that I have to manually rsync all of the dirs over, I'm curious what the stack actually does?

**Edit**

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    image: "api"
    command: rails server -b "0.0.0.0" -e production
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      resources:
        cpus: "0.1"
        memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env-prod
    networks:
      - apinet
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  client:
    image: "client"
    depends_on:
      - api
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env-prod
    networks:
      - apinet
      - clientnet
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "35730:35730"
  db:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constaints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file: .env-prod
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-volumes/app/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql/data
  redis:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constaints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-volumes/app/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
  nginx:
    image: app_nginx
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file: .env-prod
    depends_on:
      - client
      - api
    networks:
      - apinet
      - clientnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
networks:
  apinet:
    driver: overlay
  clientnet:
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't use 1 docker to run other dockers. That is not what compose is used for.

You have to set up a docker compose script in which all the machines are "[linked](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)" so that they can talk to each other. Whatever you do after that depends on the software you'd like to run. (e.g if 1 host has to use other nodes you'd provide a config file for the master machine where / how it would find the nodes).

#### An example:

Take a look at the [docker-compose file I made for my ELK-stack](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/Dockerfiles/tree/master/Elasticsearch%20%2B%20kibana)
In that file I declare 2 machines (Elasticsearch and Kibana) and I link them together with the (now deprecated) links tag. (this now happens semi-automagically, see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) for more details.)

Then in the [kibana.yml](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/Dockerfiles/blob/master/Elasticsearch%20%2B%20kibana/kibana/kibana.yml) file (at line 10) I point the Kibana machine to the Elasticsearch machine (using it's docker-compose name/linkname).

This enables the Kibana instance (imagine this would be a host) to talk to its respective Elasticsearch instance (image this would be a slave machine).

Next up your last statement:

> I would expect to be able to docker-machine ssh host. And then inside
>   of that shell be able to docker-compose up.

This is true to some extent, you can get access to an interactive (bash) shell in the Docker by using the following command:

```
docker exec --ti {ID/NAME of docker} /bin/bash
```

This won't allow you to run docker-compose though as this would most certainly lead to a variation of the infamous [Droste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect) effect:

[image: Droste effect - https://www.flickr.com/photos/subblue/sets/72157609140149244/]

[Picture source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/subblue/sets/72157609140149244/).

#### Your new question

> If it's true that I have to manually rsync all of the dirs over, I'm
>   curious what the stack actually does?

No you do not have to manually do this, you can use persistent storage in your containers to access the data from the other folders. You'd basically assign a local folder to hold the data and then "bind" that folder to the docker machine(s). Thus allowing the dockers to access the data freely. Read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) for more info.

As for the stack, stack is used in the docker cloud and serves the same general purpose as the docker-compose script. It does offer some extra deployment options seeing as you deploy to docker-cloud rather than a single docker instance. Again, read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/stack-yaml-reference/) for more info.

#### Your docker-in-docker edit

Because of your latest edit I feel obligated to go into more detail about the docker-in-docker thing.

Running docker containers in docker is generally [not recommended](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).
It is possible though, it has even been featured in the [docker blog](https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/).

Let me reiterate though, **your use case requires sibling containers not nested containers**. Please read my post again but keep an open mind to the idea of sibling containers. If you have any (specific) questions about it I will be able to help you way better ;)

#### Setting up a "docker-machine"

Setting up docker can be done a thousand ways, one of the ways I do it can be found at this [github](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/Scripts/tree/master/docker) page.

I wrote that tutorial for a friend, it covers the install of docker and the auto startup of docker machines (using both docker run and docker-compose).

Take from it what you will, it has served me well in the past :)

I highly recommend installing [Portainer](https://github.com/portainer/portainer) to manage / check up on your containers.

Comment: I have attached a docker compose file. The problem that I have is that the docker-compose file is in a separate universe than the docker machine. I don't understand what the docker machine does when I create it. How can I use the docker machine in a way that makes use of the compose file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this. The docker-compose file serves to set up the network of dockers. After setting up the dockers the compose files essentially becomes useless.

As for the directory question I'll ammend a bit to my answer

Comment: In heroku, I run `git push heroku master` and that causes the build to occur on the production machine.  When I build a docker machine, it is unaware of the services and containers that are in my compose file. How can I boot up my containers inside of a docker machine?  Like literally what command would I run to start the services inside of a docker machine?  Assuming I have a master node at "master" how can I populate that node and start running containers inside of it. Basically, what is the production equivalent of `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Please read my answer as you can **not** do what you want to do. You simply can't set up a "master" docker like you're describing. As I said in my answer you don't run dockers from inside another docker. That's just not what you do. Please read some more documentation as I feel you miss the point of the docker-compose or docker-stack commands entirely. You're talking more and more about provisioning in your comments.

To answer your question though, the equivelant command to run a docker-stack (ala docker-compose up) would be: docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml

Comment: OK that all makes sense. I definitely have some reading to do. I guess to me there's a definite disconnect between docker in development and production. In development it is very obvious how to get containers running. I understand how to create a docker machine but I don't get how the containers run on it.  I want it to function like a server.  At this point its an empty box that does nothing.  I'm struggling to describe what it should do because it seems obvious that it should behave exactly the same as development. The services should talk and be accessible, etc.

Comment: Oh is **that** what you mean with docker machine! Let me append another bit of info for ya :)

Comment: Yes! I just want it to be a place where I can run my application. I'm using poor wording because I've just started learning Docker.  Again, thanks for your patience.

Comment: I have added a section about setting up a docker-machine. It points to an (slightly older) github repo which goes through the installation and set up of a docker host machine. It takes a general ubuntu machine and transforms it into a powerful docker host :)

Comment: No problem! Communication is hard sometimes, especially when learning. Have fun with your dockers and have a great day :D

Comment: @user3162553, did you manage to achieve what you were trying to do in heroku, and how?

Comment: @suisgrand I don't believe that it's possible with heroku. I've since used deis and kubernetes to handle production builds.